# How can my custom ActionView/ActionProvider be notified when the action bar is cramped?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I've implemented a **custom `ActionProvider`**, not unlike the `ShareActionProvider`. It is however a bit wider because I included a text label that is not present in the `ShareActionProvider`.

I've noticed that regular action items (with `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM` and `SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT`) are displayed as **just icons** when in portrait configuration, and as icons with a label in landscape configuration in the action bar of my Galaxy Nexus phone. I presume that on different configurations this situation may differ. **The intention of my custom added label is the same.**

*How can I check in code if my `ActionProvider`, more specifically my equivalent of the `ActivityChooserView`, **should display the label or not**?* What future-proof way is there to get to this knowledge that is probably mostly in `ActionMenuPresenter`? Are there any safe shortcuts I can take, such as just checking portrait or landscape? Or can it be notified somehow?

---

As a *bonus question*, the `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM` seems to base itself on the number of action items, rather than their widths. As any `ActionProvider` view is already very wide, it leaves no room for a title, and yet the other action item (with `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM`) is not moved to the overflow menu. My custom `ActionProvider` will be slightly larger than 50% of the width even on some devices, yet I thought this was a rule in `ActionMenuPresenter`? How can I get better, yet still dynamic, control over this (at a high level)?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems I might be able to use `mAllowTextWithIcon` in `ActionMenuItemView` (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java) and copy the AOSP's config resource structure for it.